# 'identifier' already has a body but identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I have a Qt project using precompiled headers (not sure if that's relevant) in VS2012 and it compiles and works fine. But when I try to compile the same project in QtCreator it shows errors. First of all - both projects correspond to each other and were previously correctly configured (they compiled and worked just fine). After latest changes to the code, however, something went wrong.

Errors:

```
pch.h:34: error:C2084: function 'void handleExceptionByShowingMessage(std::exception &)' already has a body
main.cpp:16: error:C3861: 'handleExceptionByShowingMessage': identifier not found
```

These go on for 30+ lines with another function defined in pch.h (inline too) and a few more cpp files. But all errors are analogical.

From `pch.h`:

```
inline void handleExceptionByShowingMessage(std::exception &e)
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)e.what()));
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Discard);
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    int ret = msgBox.exec();
}
```

I don't paste function calls from `cpp` files because it's just a regular use. All `cpp` files include `pch.h` correctly (first line of code) and as I said - the exactly same code and file structure works in VS2012 (whose compiler, I believe, QtCreator actually uses...).

If you need more code/information please let me know.

**Update:**
Yes, all headers have `#pragma once`. **Interesting notice though** - when I moved these two function definitions to a dummy header file and included it in the `pch.h`, the project compiled fine.

Comment: Do you have an include guard or a #pragma once in your pch.h?

Comment: Yes, of course. Also please see the update to my question.

Comment: I suspect `pch.h` gets included twice - once while loading precompiled headers, once while parsing the file itself, which `#pragma once` won't protect agaisnt.

Comment: Seems like it but do you have any idea what can be done (besides using dummy header file)?

Comment: You could try using an include guard instead (#ifndef PCH #define PCH #endif) but I think you shouldn't put anything besides #includes in you PCH anyway, since it's meant to be an optimization and not part of the source code.

Comment: Not sure why but apparently Qt has a problem with `#pragma once` (or it doesn't support it at all) - changing to `#ifndef` solved the problem. Make your comment an answer and get accepted.

Comment: Done -- with additional explanations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#pragma once` only prevents the file containing the directive from being included several times. You precompiled header file, `pch.h`, gets included when the precompiled headers are loaded, and a second time when you files are compiled. The `#pragma` directive sees them as separate files so it won't work in this context.

The `pch.h` file (or `stdafx.h`) is an optimization and ideally should not contain source code but only `#includes` to other header files. That way, including it several times won't be an issue.

Another solution would be using an include guard (`#ifndef PCH #define PCH #endif`), which will prevent the file to be included several times.

Answer (score 1):

you may try `static inline` if the code is in header.
I do not know why `inline` does not imply `static` but i also stumbled about this a time ago.